# Textbox input as a path for Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, textbox

My aim is to have a window with a textbox and a button, enter a file path into the textbox and click the button to run an FnR function using the file path from the textbox.

So far, I have a working GUI and the PowerShell script for FnR.

```
##omitted most of the script##

$button1.Add_Click({Convert})

Function Convert {
    (.Get-ChildItem "C:\target.txt" -Recurse).FullName |
        ForEach-Object {...}
```

Works fine.

I can't for the life of me find how to change "C:\target.txt" to take the text from the textbox as a path.

Comment: something like: `get-childitem $txtBoxVariable.Text `

Comment: Fixing the typos in the code might help, too (`Covert`<->`Convert`, `-Recourse`<->`-Recurse`).

Comment: Thank you! Typos aren't present in the actual script, I retyped it badly.

Comment: Thank you both! The $textboxvar.Text works!!! I thought I tried that but I think I messed it up by trying to include a default value.